# Acessing array inside form variable sent

Tags: arrays, post, coldfusion

I`m working with PayPal and I need this block of code to read the post Payment Responses of API:

```
<cfif StructKeyExists(FORM.TRANSACTION[0],"ID_FOR_SENDER_TXN")>
    <cfset pTxnId = FORM.TRANSACTION[0].ID_FOR_SENDER_TXN />
</cfif>
```

But when I runs the payment response test tool, I got this error: 500 Element TRANSACTION is undefined in a Java object of type class [Ljava.lang.String;.

I used this loop:

```
<cfloop collection="#form#" item="theField">
        <cfif theField is not "fieldNames">
            #theField# = #form[theField]#<br>
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
```

to see the variables sent in FORM and the variables is like this:

- TRANSACTION[0].ID_FOR_SENDER_TXN
- TRANSACTION[0].IS_PRIMARY_RECEIVER
- TRANSACTION[0].RECEIVER TRANSACTION[0].AMOUNT
- TRANSACTION[0].STATUS_FOR_SENDER_TXN

I don't know why I can't access this.

**(Update from comments)**

Tried use this code:

```
<cfif isDefined("form['FORM.TRANSACTION[0].ID_FOR_SENDER_TXN']")> 
     <cfset pTxnId = form['FORM.TRANSACTION[0].ID_FOR_SENDER_TXN'] />  
</cfif>
```

Now I am getting the error:

> 500 Parameter 1 of function IsDefined, which is now
>   form['FORM.TRANSACTION[0].ID_FOR_SENDER_TXN'], must be a syntactically
>   valid variable name.

Same error if I use

```
form['FORM.TRANSACTION[0].ID_FOR_SENDER_TXN']
```

or

```
form['TRANSACTION[0].ID_FOR_SENDER_TXN']
```

**Update 2**

Worked with:

```
<cfif structKeyExists(FORM, "TRANSACTION[0].ID_FOR_SENDER_TXN")>

</cfif>
```

Thank you!

Comment: ... so following [what Adam said](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18191815/104223), the correct syntax for structKeyExists is `structKeyExists(FORM, "TRANSACTION[0].ID_FOR_SENDER_TXN")`. Note: You **cannot use IsDefined** here, because of the special characters in the field name ie `[]` and `.`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the form field name is `TRANSACTION[0].ID_FOR_SENDER_TXN` (which is what your debugging loop is indicating), then you should address it as:

```
form['FORM.TRANSACTION[0].ID_FOR_SENDER_TXN']
```

To clarify:

When you access a variable using this notation:

```
<cfset pTxnId = FORM.TRANSACTION[0].ID_FOR_SENDER_TXN />
```

ColdFusion expects this data structure:

http://note.io/15v3o51

It looks for a key in the form named transaction, and tries to get the 0th index from it (side note: this wouldn't work in CF anyway, arrays begin with index 1), and as that first item in the array, it's expecting a structure with a key named ID_FOR_SENDER_TXN.

However, what PayPal is sending you is actually using this format:

http://note.io/19nTSZR

This explains the error message: "Element TRANSACTION is undefined in a Java object of type class [Ljava.lang.String;."

Comment: Right, but how is possible to access the variable passed by paypal response with index 0, if the coldfusion only reads index 1+?

Comment: Use "array notation" to access the object of the structure; and re-read my answer. It's not an array, it's a form field NAME that LOOKS like an array.